# BREW not found after swtiching from ZSH to BASH

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, zsh

I switch my shell from `ZSH` to `BASH` and when I try to use BREW I get the following:

```
mac01:~ jdoe$ brew search python
-bash: brew: command not found
mac01:~ jdoe$
```

Here is the `$PATH` from both shells:

From `ZSH`:

```
jdoe@mac01 ~ $echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

From `BASH`:

```
mac01:~ jdoe$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: `~/.bashrc` vs `~/.zshrc` discrepancy?

Comment: This is what my ~/.zshrc looks like:

alias python3=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

And this is what my ~/.bashrc looks like:

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Comment: @daquezada : Obviously `brew` is not in one of the directories in the PATH. Why don't you set your PATH so that it contains the desired directory? If you are not sure about the location, you an (inside a zsh, where you know that `brew` is found), do a `type brew` to see the directory.

Answer (score 0):

By default brew binary located in `/usr/local/bin/brew`, if brew is not found, it means `/usr/local/bin` is not on $PATH. So you should look what does $PATH contain in bash and then append `/usr/local/bin/` if required

Comment: This is what my ~/.zshrc looks like:

alias python3=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

And this is what my ~/.bashrc looks like:

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Comment: @daquezada, pls show us ur $PATH from different shells (`echo $PATH`)

Comment: From ZSH:

daquezada@mac01 ~ $echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin


From BASH:

mac01:~ daquezada$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Do you have a ```source ~/.bashrc``` in your `.bash_profile`? Mainly in macos bashrc is located in /etc/bashrc and for profile-wide it's `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: You should uncomment it, to work with `.bashrc`

Comment: Ok.  I just un-commented, then what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that I did not have `XCode` installed.

I installed `XCode` and then re-install `Homebrew` and now everything is working as it is supposed to.

Thanks all for your help.